# What does "shipping up" mean in this song title?

Tags: meaning

In this [Dropkick Murphys song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x-64CaD8GXw), what does "shipping up" mean in the title?

> I'm Shipping Up To Boston

I've looked for it in three different dictionaries. None of them contain "ship up". So maybe there is someone who can help for me.

Comment: To [ship](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ship) means "to send something, usually a large object or a large quantity of objects or people, to a place far away".  *I'm Shipping / Up To Boston*. The singer is going to Boston, possibly relocating to Boston.

Comment: If I am shipping up, I am traveling. Sailors, for example, *ship out* to sea = travel away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means to travel by boat. Here's the [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ship) definition:

> **2 a :** to go or travel by ship  —often used with out

In this case, it's used with "up" rather than "out". "Up" here means north, so wherever they were travelling from, it was south of Boston.